# Spring, catch exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have small problem. I can't catch exception in method. I need to catch `ConstraintViolationException` to process it. Somebody know why it happens?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.save(customer);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.debug(e);
        // Process exception
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't catch it? What do you expect to happen (and why) and what happens instead?

Comment: First don't catch the exception and process it as that will break transaction management. The exception will only occur if something happens to the database, save doesn't trigger the actual persisting of the changes. The commit of the transaction does. You need to force a flush of the changes to catch the exception, but as stated your current approach will break proper transaction management.

Comment: Do toy want to validate your customer entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  ran into similar problem some days  ago.
I looked at the StackTrace and used `PersistenceException`.

Try it:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.save(customer);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        log.debug(e);
        // Process exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on question, it looks like `session.save(..)` is not throwing exception at all but rather persisting entity into db. Can you check if your `customer` object got saved into db after this method got executed.

You might be looking for unique key constraint violation or some sort but `session.save(..)` is saving entity into db. You might need to check your how you have defined your `Customer` entity as well.